# Axis Camera. Raw Image

Tags: ros, roslaunch, camera, image, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with an axis camera. It provides the compressed image in jpg format (stream video). However, I need the raw image to calibrate the camera.
As camera does not provide the raw image, I use the next command

rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=image_raw raw out:=image_raw

And it works. But I would like to include it in the axis camera launch file as node. How could it do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209195/axis-camera.-raw-image/) by [jorgelc79](https://answers.ros.org/users/2528/jorgelc79/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! This is the launchfile that I use, hope it will helps :

```
<node name="axis_connection" pkg="axis_camera" type="axis.py"  required="true">
    <param name="hostname" value="127.0.0.7" />
    <param name="password" value="Mypasssword" />
    <param name="width" value="1280" />
    <param name="height" value="720" />
    <param name="camera_info_url" value="file://$(find axis_cam_modified)/camera_info/10_0_161_201.yaml" />
</node>

<node name="image_transport_decompressed" pkg="image_transport" type="republish" 
args="compressed in:=image_raw raw out:=image_raw //image_transport:=compressed">
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) with karma: 170 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1